# inheritance and memcpy - How is it work together?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, memcpy

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(const std::string &name) : _name(name)
    {
    }
    virtual void Print() const = 0;
    virtual ~Animal() {}
protected:
    std::string _name;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    Dog(const std::string &name, const std::string &dogtype) : Animal(name), _dogtype(dogtype)
    {
        Print();
    }
    void Print() const
    {
        std::cout << _name << " of type " << _dogtype << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string _dogtype;
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    Cat(const std::string &name, int weight) : Animal(name), _weight(weight)
    {
        Print();
    }
    virtual void Print() const
    {
        std::cout << _name << " of weight " << _weight << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Cat(){}
private:
    int _weight;
};

class Tiger : public Cat
{
public:
    Tiger(const std::string &name, int weight, double speed) : Cat(name, weight), _speed(speed)
    {
        Print();
    }
    void Print() const
    {
        std::cout << _name << " speed " << _speed << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Tiger(){std::cout << "Tiger's dtor" << std::endl;}
private:
    int _speed;
};

int main()
{
    Animal *a = new Tiger("theRealKing", 3, 40.5);
    Cat *c = new Cat("silvester", 4);
    memcpy(c, a, sizeof(Cat));
    c->Print(); /// ------------------------
    delete a;
    delete c;
    return 0;
}
```

in the line : c->Print():
the line before that c became a tiger so why does it print me this line :
Ross with speed 135081
insted of 
Ross with speed 3
why there is a memory problem ?
why does it call the print method of tiger and not of cat ?

Comment: A cat can't become a tiger!

Answer (score 11):

It *doesn't* work together.

Using `memcpy` on these objects produces *undefined behavior*, the Standard permits anything to happen.

It isn't inheritance per se that is causing you problems, but the presence of virtual member functions or custom constructor/destructor.  These make your objects lose the *trivially-copyable* classification that is *required* when using `memcpy`.

Your class isn't *trivially-copyable* for a second reason -- it contains a member of type `std::string` which is not *trivially-copyable*.

In practical terms, when you perform a bitwise copy of a `std::string` subobject, you end up with two pointers to the same memory, and both `string` objects will try to free this pointer.  That will crash your program.  If using `memcpy` on a v-table hasn't done so earlier.

But when you mix in optimizations, even weirder things can happen.  That's what *undefined behavior* means.

Comment: The problem is worse than a memory problem. It is *undefined behavior* which means that the problem could include memory, data corruption, reformatting your hard drive, corrupting your SO profile...

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using memcpy for objects in `c++`, use the copy constructor instead.